# Linux leitura correta do PID Linux

Tags: linux

Estou com uma dificuldade na leitura do PID do processo. Apresenta a mensagem abaixo, mas eu não consigo entender além do script buy.sh o que mais é apresentado.
Vi também que apresenta 2 .jar, esses processos são em fila ou são contínuos?

> root     28140 28125  0 06:50 ?        00:00:54 java -Xms256M
>   -Xmx1024M -classpath ../lib/63_CME_MessageFactoryPatch.jar:../lib/fix-application-server.jar:../resources
>   -Dcom.cameronsystems.fix.management.JMXManagementService.startupScript=/home/CameronFIX/SocketAdapter/buy.sh
>   com.cameronsystems.fix.universalserver.UniversalServer -id buy
>   -xmlconfig Buy_dsv.xml -server buy1 -cluster buyCluster_dsv -nogui

Comment: Eu não entendi bem sua pergunta. Você tem um único processo java com dois arquivos *.jar* e pasta `resource` no *classpath*. Todo o resto da linha após o *classpath*, incluindo o caminho do arquivo `buy.sh` são argumentos que você está passando para sua aplicação. O que você quer dizer com "fila" ou "contínuo" Poderia atualizar a sua pergunta com mais informações?

Answer (score 1):

Isso é um processo apenas, o PID do mesmo esta na segunda coluna da esquerda para direita. O processo é o java, o resto é parâmetros.

Você pode pegar o número do PID exato executando o comando

```
pidof nome_do_processo
```

ou

```
ps aux | grep nome_do_processo | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'
```

O retorno desses comando acima é o número exato do PID, caso tenha mais processos com o mesmo nome, irá listar mais de um número de pid.